# Orcale Database connection failure from VS-2022

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I am suddenly unable to get connected to the Oracle database from VisualStudio 2022.

The latest build is also not working after the deployment on the deployment server, I cannot see any changes in my checkout files related to the connection string but the previously hosted build is working perfectly at the deployment server.

However, I am still able to connect from SqlDeveloper.
(The only change that I can observe is the windows update)

"DefaultDb": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)));User Id=;Password=;"

Error: ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname'

[image]

[image]

Comment: `HOST=` is empty.

Comment: Well, connection details are empty as you may see